# Java/Android FileNotFoundException to many open files

Tags: java, android

I want to prefix with I have ~1 hour of Java/Android experience. I have inherited a logging application that runs on android phones from a former employee. The logging application works for about 2 minutes and then crashes due to:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/log_20200608081738.csv (Too many open files)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
        at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:107)
        at (company name/package removed)$1.run(Main.java:206)
```

Being completely novice to Java I have no idea what is happening or how to fix it. Below is the code that is causing the issue. Essentially:

- The logger runs on a separate thread
- The logger has a queue that other threads push Strings to that they
  need logged
- The logger then just `takes` an item from the queue and writes it
  using a `BufferedWriter`

My two questions are:

1. How to fix the exceptions being thrown. I can catch the exceptions
   but I would like to actually solve this. When we start to
   incorporate other parts of the application the whole thing crashes. Maybe its the other part of the application that is causing the crash and its just being caught here? If that is the case how would I find out?
2. Is there a better `Java\Android` approach to take?

Here is the infinite loop that logs data from the queue:

```
    public void run() {
        String line = "";
            do {
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
                    try {
                        line = logQueue.take();
                        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
                        bufferedWriter.write(line);
                        bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                           try {
                               bufferedWriter.close();
                           }
                           catch (IOException e) {

                           }
                        }
                    }

                } while (!line.equals("END"));
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: At minimum, you need to close your `Writer`.

Comment: @CommonsWare does that not happen in the finally block? Not sure if thats what you are referring to being new to java.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Other code that is calling the code you posted is likely to be keeping more than 1024 files open, which is an OS limit that you can change. In this case, I'll refrain from commenting because I'm no sysop, but your IT team and Google are your friends here. On your side, you can keep a count of the number of open files and limit the number of concurrent calls at some threshold < your file limit.